# Can Boruta be used for inference about which variables matter?

Tags: regression, inference, random-forest, boruta

In particular with Boruta variable selection.

If not, what is a better approach?

Edit: In terms of the spectrum from prediction to inference, I am interested in the latter. That is, I am interested in understanding the relationship between the predictors and the outcome measure in my data (rather than building the best model to predict new data).

I was told that random forests with boruta is a good approach for prediction, but not for inference. I'm wondering if this is true? If it is, what would be a better analysis for my goal?

Edit 2:  I would like to know if observations that are high on the DV vs low on the DV have different patterns in terms of the predictor variables.

Comment: The purpose of [tag:Boruta] is to carry out feature selection, and is one way of determining which features "matter." In light of that, it's hard to understand what, specifically, you're asking about. Are you asking how Boruta works? Or something else? Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: @Sycorax I've added more details. Hope this clears it up!

Comment: If you mean inference in the sense of hypothesis testing, then "no".

Comment: @MichaelM Can you suggest an alternative?

Comment: What inference are you trying to make, and how does feature selecting fit in with helping you make that inference?

Comment: @Sycorax I would like to know if observations that are high on the DV vs low on the DV have different patterns in terms of the predictor variables.

Comment: Please edit your question to include this information.